# Different IntelliJ Cursive and `lein repl` performance characteristics

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

The following totally brings Cursive IntelliJ REPL to its knees whereas it runs fine in a REPL outside IDE:

```
(def r (range 1e7))
(let
[
lazy1 (take 1000000 r)
lazy2 (take 2000000 r)
]
(do
(time (vec lazy1)) 
(time (vec lazy1)) 
(time (vec lazy2)) 
(time (vec lazy2)) 
)
)
```

Is that 'by design' or am I missing some kind of configuration?

Thanks.